# JSON control character error, without a control character

Tags: php, json

Im using JSON to transfer data from my server to my client and vice versa. I compress chat message strings with LZString to save space. This works fine, except for 4 character messages (so "abcd", "xyzs" etc).
Everything works fine, but the JSON doesn't get decoded correctly. My PHP code (checked via json_last_error_msg) tells me that I have a

```
Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

So I checked and it seems that control characters are mainly formatting issues, like line breaks, tabs etc.
I checked my JSON with JSONLint and it says its fine, so I really don't know where the error lies. Heres a sample JSON output with a 4 character message:

```
{ "code": "CHAT_SEND_MESSAGE", "args": ["ALL","ÒÄçþéåÓ╣ñ "]}
```

It seems to be an error with the space at the end of the string in args. Because some 4 character signs (like "Ôåä´ìÇ") work, while everything with a space at the end gives a control character error (like "ÔåéÒâå╔ñ " or the message above). Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: You cannot put binary data in the middle of a JSON string. Why not encode the whole JSON object (and decode it again before parsing)?

Comment: Which compression method in LZString are you using? There seem to be safer/more portable methods than the default "compress" (which "produces invalid UTF-16 strings" according to the documentation).

Comment: @Thilo yeah thanks, compressToUTF16 fixes the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are control characters, which seems to you like a space. for example have a look at the ASCII 0-31 http://ascii-code.com/

Maybe try to copy-paste into Windows Editor (not Notepad++ or word) and pasting back into your json data.

Comment: I parsed the whole string through ord() and apparently the space is a null character (ASCII code 0).

Comment: that is your answer. JSON permits Null character!. Don't forget to upvote, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, apparently LZString does that sometimes, I changed the compression method as suggested above and now it works.